# Visual Studio project publishes, but no content

Tags: visual-studio

Good Day

I want to publish a project in Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate. Now it publishes fine (as a File System to C:\Projects), BUT, when opening the folder it publishes in C:\Projects...There is nothing. It is empty. Why is that?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of project is it? does it contain code files or just content/resources?

Comment: Code files and everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem . Just try deleting your current profile and add a new profile for the project.